# Can't get id from url to use in 'To' field of Rails ActionMailer

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4.2.6 app, I have the following workflow:

Logged-in Member A searches for a trainer, reviews Trainer B's profile, and decides to send Trainer B an email to ask a question.  The original email from Member A is delivered to the app's domain, which forwards the message with instructions to Trainer B.  The forwarded message contains a "Reply_to" field, so Trainer B can reply directly to Member A.  The search feature and the delivery of the original message from Member A to the domain works as expected.  However, I can't figure out how to get the trainer's id from the url to forward the email to the correct trainer.

Here what I've done, but with no success....

Passed the trainer's id via a link_to on the Trainer's profile page (/views/trainers/show.html.erb):

```
<li id="up-next-email-trainer"><p><%= link_to 'Email trainer', new_email_path(:trainer => { :trainer_id => @trainer.id }), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %></p></li>
```

When a member clicks the above link, the page redirects to an email form at the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/emails/new?trainer%5Btrainer_id%5D=5
```

where 5 is the correct id of the trainer for this example. I'm trying to use request original_url to grab the trainer id and store it in a variable.

However, when the member fills out the form and clicks the 'Send email' button, it triggers the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /emails
Couldn't find Trainer with 'id'=s
```

It looks like the url is being cut off; the trainer's id is not getting passed.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my emails_controller.rb:

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :get_trainer

  def new
    @email = Email.new  
  end

  def create
    @email = Email.new(email_params)

    if @email.valid?
      # Delivers email to app domain, then forward message
      EmailMailer.email_trainer(@email).deliver_now
      redirect_to user_path(current_user),
       notice: "Your message was sent successfully. Check your email account for a response soon."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def email_params
    params.require(:email).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :content)
  end

  def get_trainer
    params[:id] = request.original_url.last       
    @trainer = Trainer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

email_mailer.rb:

```
class EmailMailer < ApplicationMailer

  default :to => "........@gmail.com"

  def email_trainer(email)
        @email = email
        mail from: "#{ @email.name } <#{ @email.email }>",
         subject: @email.subject,
         body: @email.content,
         reply_to: @email.email  

     # Forwards email message to trainer
        get_trainer
        mail to: @trainer.email,
        subject: "An important message for trainer",
        body: "A member has sent you an email ....\nHere's the message:  '#{ @email.content }'\nReply directly to #{ @email.name } at #{ @email.email }.",
        reply_to: @email.email
    end
end
```

email.rb:

```
class Email
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :content

  ... validation code here ...
end
```

*** EDIT *****
Relevant code from the email form (/emails/new.html.erb):

```
  <%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :style => 'width: 50%' }, :placeholder => "Your name" %>
  <%= f.input :email, :input_html => { :style => 'width: 50%' }, :placeholder => "Your email address" %>
  <%= f.input :subject, :input_html => { :style => 'width: 50%' }, :placeholder => "Short subject line" %>
  <%= f.input :content, :as => :text, :input_html => { :id => 'email_textbox', :style => 'width: 50%' }, :placeholder => "Write your message here..." %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit 'Send email', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

**** EDIT - Log from Post action  ****

```
    Started POST "/emails" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-20 14:14:23 -0700
    ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
    Processing by EmailsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YYOhw0Z9Fghoa5oeAke5KVcE2yHdLcUUDYvYjNDXPEDsS0i0QZNRoAncF2kmEjIBV+V9FrQbnQ2ve9mJoFllYA==", "email"=>{"name"=>"Jo Tester", "email"=>"jotester@example.com", "subject"=>"Testing", "content"=>"Testing mailer"}, "trainer"=>{"trainder_id"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Send email"}
    User Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    Trainer Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "trainers".* FROM "trainers" WHERE "trainers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
    Completed 404 Not Found in 323ms (ActiveRecord: 22.1ms)

    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Trainer with 'id'=:
    activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
    () home/ronald/projects/gym-app/app/controllers/emails_controller.rb:32:in `get_trainer'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
    activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
    actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
    warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
    warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
    activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
    activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
    activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
    better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
    better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
    better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
    activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
    actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
    thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
    thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
    thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    eventmachine (1.2.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
    thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
    rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    () home/ronald/projects/gym-app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    spring (1.7.1) bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    spring (1.7.1) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    () home/XX/projects/XX-XX/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    () rails:3:in `<main>'

    Started POST "/__better_errors/4761d84c9ca9f7a7/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-20 14:14:24 -0700
    Trainer Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "trainers".* FROM "trainers"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller

```
EmailMailer.email_trainer(@email, @trainer).deliver_now
```

and in the mailer

```
def email_trainer(email, trainer)
    @email = email
    @trainer = trainer
    mail from: "#{ @email.name } <#{ @email.email }>",
     subject: @email.subject,
     body: @email.content,
     reply_to: @email.email  

    # Forwards email message to trainer
    mail to: @trainer.email,
    subject: "An important message for trainer",
    body: "A member has sent you an email ....\nHere's the message:  '#{ @email.content }'\nReply directly to #{ @email.name } at #{ @email.email }.",
    reply_to: @email.email
end
```

READY!

Comment: When I remove the get_trainer method, it triggers 
NoMethodError at /emails/new
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass  This error references the hidden field in the form.

Comment: Dennis, this is working!  I had forgotten to remove the call of the get_trainer method from email_mailer.rb.  Thanks much for all your help.  I will accept the revised answer and mark the other answers with 1 point each, because all of them helped me solve the issue.  Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
def get_trainer
  params[:id] = request.original_url.last       
  @trainer = Trainer.find(params[:id])
end
```

to:

```
def get_trainer
  @trainer = Trainer.find(params[:trainer][:trainer_id])
end
```

Never overload the params

Comment: Thanks for reply, however, I'm now getting the following error:  
NoMethodError at /emails
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: AH!.. sorry i read wrong!.. You are not sending the trainer_id in the form!! you need to add hidden field in the form with the trainer[trainer_id] or change the params only trainer_id in the link and the hidden field in the form

Comment: I'm not sure how/where to add a hidden field.  I had read something about a hidden field before posting so it sounds like I'm close to getting this working.  I edited my post to include relevant code from my email form.  Can you show me where /how to add a hidden field to the form?

Comment: I addded a new answer

Comment: Still throws NameError at /emails
undefined local variable or method `get_trainer'

Comment: if you note i removed get_trainer from mailer and pass the trainer by param to mailer method like last answer

Answer (score 1):

Add it:

```
.....
 your fields are here...
    <%= hidden_field_tag "trainer[trainer_id]", @trainer.id%>
</div>

<div class="actions">
.....
```

Comment: I added the hidden field, but getting this error now:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /emails
Couldn't find Trainer with 'id'=
I have this code in emails_controller.rb:
def get_trainer @trainer = Trainer.find(params[:trainer][:trainer_id]) end

Comment: paste the log post action

Comment: added the log of post action.

Comment: it wrong type: trainder_id is trainer... i re-edit my answer correcting .. jejejeje

Comment: it wrong type: trainder_id is trainer_id... I re-edit my answer correcting the hidden field .. jejejeje It must work now

Comment: Now I'm getting a NameError at /emails
undefined local variable or method `get_trainer'

Comment: Removed the before_action get trainer. Now error is "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass"  For some reason, it looks like the method is being called when there is no trainer. Trainer is nil.  Hmmm?

Comment: keep the private action get_trainer and must work, like first answer

Comment: To clarify ... with the private "get_trainer" method in the controller, I'm getting NameError at /emails undefined local variable or method `get_trainer'

Comment: before_action to before_filter or test became from private to public method

Comment: changed to before_filter but got same NameError.  Tried changing method to public, but got same NameError.  Calling the method did NOT throw a NameError with the code in my original post.  What might be causing it now?

Comment: I READ ALL. your new problem is in the mailer now... is new problem. you need to send @trainer to mailer and you cannt call get_trainer action controller in the mailer..

Comment: Okay, I'll continue my troubleshooting of this issue.  Thanks for all your time.  I am going to accept your answer about including the "hidden field" because that helps me get closer to getting my mailer to work. I appreciate your help ... any other thoughts about this problem are appreciated too.

Comment: I added new answer with the solution